# Page number doesn't show anymore (Word 2003)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

I've a weird problem : i "see" the tags of MS-Word app instead of their values. This is the case for the table of content, page number etc.

Tags are like {PAGE} {NUMPAGES} {TOC \0 "1-3" \h \z \u}

Even in the "page view".

What have I done to deserve this (well know song) ?

I've thru all the settings of this app but I didn't find the right check-box to be checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Go to Tools -> Options -> View -> Show - Uncheck(clear) the field codes.

Answer (score 0):

A quicker way to do this (toggle display of field codes) is to press **Alt+F9** - Windows or **Opt+F9** - Mac.

*On some computers, these shortcuts may require that an **Fn** key be pressed at the same time.*