# Field-Code tables don't preview or print (Word-2003)

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2003, field-codes

When I go to preview or print a Word 2003 document, the "table of contents", "table of figures" and the "table of tables", visible while editing in "Print Layout" mode, are suddenly replaced by their fields codes , e.g. `{TOC \o "1-3"}`.

In preview mode I can force them to re-appear when I press , same as one would use to toggle visibility in editing mode.

I still can't find a way to actually print my document with TOC .

Toggling field code visibility, as explained in the accepted answer to the question ([page-number-doesnt-show-anymore-word-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/112930/page-number-doesnt-show-anymore-word-2003)) makes no difference.

Since a colleague is able to print the documents I authored, and the problem exists for all documents I look at, I assume it is a local setting and not a broken document.

But toggling the settings under **Tools->Options->View** or **Tools->Options->Print** doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer as I was writing up the question ...

The solution was in an unexpected place: open the Print-Options dialogue (File->Print->Options) and uncheck "Include with Document"->"Field codes".

It seems this option can be set global with **Tools->Options->Print** and over riden per printer with **File->Print->Options**,

nice if you know, but a nightmare if you dont!